# Are we using the axiom of choice when we utilize a theorem a countable number of times?

Tags: set-theory

Lets say I have a sequence $(V_n)$ of open sets and a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact sets. For each pair $(V_n,K_n)$, Urysohn's lemma gives a function $f_n$ with some nice properties.

My question is: in order to form a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions I have to use the axiom of countable choice?

I can imagine arguing that Urysohn's lemma only gives me the information that the set $\{f_n\:|\: f_n\text{ satisfies a 'nice' property}\}$ is non-empty. But in order to actually have a function, I am doing a choice.

Also, I can imagine that Urysohn's lemma actually gives me a function, and so no choice is needed.

What argument is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urysohn's lemma itself requires the Axiom of (Dependent) Choice.

However, once you have chosen the functions, the axiom of replacement tells you that your collection of functions is a set without the need for choice. And the function $\Bbb N\to \{f_n\}$ that makes it a sequence also doesn't require choice to be constructed.

Comment: I don't know if I understood it very well. You're saying that we can see Urysohn's lemma as a function $U$ that accepts pairs $(V_n,K_n)$ of open and compact sets and outputs a function?

If that is the case, given that I accept Urysohn's lemma and that I have sequences of open sets $(V_n)$ and compact sets $(K_n)$, then I don't need the axiom of choice to form a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions such that [...] ?

Comment: @Gabriel I'm saying that making each of the $f_n$ through Urysohn's lemma does require some form of choice. Once you have the functions, making the set that contains them and turning it into a sequence does _not_ require choice.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understood your use of the axiom of replacement.

Comment: @Gabriel $\Bbb N$ is a set, and for each element in $\Bbb N$ we have assigned a pair $(V_n, K_n)$. That makes the collection of all such pairs a set by replacement. Now, for each pair, Urysohn's gives us a function. Thus by replacement, the collection of these functions is a set.

Comment: @Arthur are you saying that the relation between $(V_n,K_n)$ and $f$ is functional because Urysohn provides a unique rule how to compute the function (e.g. in Munkres $f(x) = \inf \{ p \in \mathbb{Q} : x \in U_p \}$)?